# Font of old math books

Tags: fonts

I really like the font (for the text mainly, not necessarily for the math) used in math books from the 40s-60s. I am for instance thinking of the font in [Halmos' Measure Theory](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387900889). Anybody knows which fonts were used in such books and if there is a modern equivalent?

Comment: I got curious and asked WhatTheFont (https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/). Apparently the closest match is "P22 Mayflower Smooth". However, whether there is a LaTeX variant of this proprietary font, I cannot say. Maybe you want to go through the LaTeX Font catalogue (http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/seriffonts.html)

Comment: I don't think this question is the same as the one Henri Menke posted. I am not interested in a particular symbol, I am interested in the font used to typeset a whole book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got curious and asked [WhatTheFont](http://myfonts.com/WhatTheFont). Apparently the closest match is "P22 Mayflower Smooth".

As this is a commercial font, you might need to buy it, and you will probably only be able to obtain `ttf` and `otf` versions. However, if you are able to get hold of it, `XeLaTeX` interacts with it nicely.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setmainfont{P22Mayflower}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: P22Mayflower]

Comment: I think this is a close match. I myself found Century Old Style Roman, which is from 1909 and was used in many books from the first half of the 20th century.