# Font in maths books

Tags: fonts

I would like to know what is this beautiful font used to typeset maths books as
[J.D. Moore's *Lectures on Seiber-Witten theory*](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540412212)
and [S. Morita's *Geometry of differential forms*](https://books.google.pl/books?id=5N33Of2RzjsC&pg=PA2&hl=pl&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false).

This font is much different than the one in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338765/font-of-old-math-books).

I tried to use [What The Font](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) tool, but all fonts it suggested were much different. [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/) said that it was similar to [Century Old Style](http://www.identifont.com/show?5ZZ). It looks like quite a good match, yet they look different.

Then I tried to use `pdffonts`. It gave me the following:

```
Times Bold                           TrueType          WinAnsi          yes no  no      23  0
Times Roman                          TrueType          WinAnsi          yes no  no      26  0
Times Italic                         TrueType          WinAnsi          yes no  no      37  0
Helvetica Bold Oblique               TrueType          WinAnsi          yes no  no      56  0
TCNFTU+HiddenHorzOCR                 CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     67  0
Helvetica                            TrueType          WinAnsi          yes no  no      88  0
```

This however does not look as Helvetica to me (I tried [this](https://gist.github.com/Pni0/2923266)) nor Times Roman from `mathptmx` package.

I wonder if you recognize this font. (Any idea what other tool I can use is very welcome :)

Comment: The first book was published by Springer. Some decades ago, Springer had developped his own version of `Minion` for maths. Don't know whether this publisher still uses them, though.

Comment: Ah, Minion looks like that's the font from the Morita. My age-addled brain had forgotten all about that font.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Moore book is Computer Modern, the default font in LaTeX.

The Morita I'm not placing at the moment. It's got the look of something post-Baskerville, but it's not anything in the Century family (note the foot of the lowercase b). Perhaps try the what the font forums?

Edit: Bernard probably has the font from Morita correctly identified as Minion.