# Old mathbook's thick font

Tags: fonts, fontsize, math-fonts

I did a lot of research to re-create the style of the following math book written in 1979:

[image]

There are many questions around recreating old fonts such as
[font-of-old-math-books](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338765/font-of-old-math-books) , [how-to-write-like-old-mathematical-papers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352447/how-to-write-like-old-mathematical-papers) ,
[old-books-appearance-and-font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398522/old-books-appearance-and-font) and I found that the closest would be the *Old Standard* font in XeLatex.

I noticed, that the older fonts are always a big **bolder** than the Latex fonts, including *Old Standart*.

**Does anybody know a more suitable, thicker font or a way to thicken (increase the weight of) the font for the whole Latex document?
And can you identify the math font (and make it thicker as well?**

There are some solutions to the last questions in [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27843/level-of-boldness-changeable), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352447/how-to-write-like-old-mathematical-papers), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225027/how-to-create-new-font-which-is-thicker-version-of-computer-modern) but I did not find a solution how to scale it *globally*.

Comment: Given the use of $\leqq$ and $\geqq$ elsewhere (i.e. with a full horizontal = below the < or >) , is $u\le t$ (with just a - below the <) a misprint for $u\leqq t$?

Comment: Old books printed from metal type exhibited "ink squash" resulting from the pressure of the inked type against the paper.  This is not true for books printed using digital type, and especially not when the design of the digital type is based on the shapes of the metal letters, not on their printed results.  (I know this doesn't help you find what you're looking for, but it's sometimes useful to know why something is so.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]

Fonts in the computer modern family are very light by design, so most other font choices are bolder, but here I have forced the Times-like TeX Gyre Termes and Stix Two Math fonts to be adjusted to be bolder (but less bold than the designed bold font)

Credit to [mathpix](https://mathpix.com/) for ocr your image to error free LaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[FakeBold=1]
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[FakeBold=1]

\begin{document}

\textbf{Example}

In particular, if $X_A\left(t, t_0\right), X_A\left(t_\theta, t_0\right)=I, X_B\left(t, t_0\right), X_B\left(t_0, t_0\right)=I$, are fundamental matrix solutions of $\dot{x}=A(t) x, \dot{y}=B(t) y$, respectively, then
\[
\begin{aligned}
\left|X_A\left(t, t_0\right)-X_B\left(t, t_0\right)\right| \leqq & \sup _{t_0 \leqq u \leq t}\left|X_B\left(u, t_0\right)\right|\left(\exp \int_{t_0}^t|A(s)| d s\right) \\
& \times \int_{t_0}^t|A(s)-B(s)| d s
\end{aligned}
\]
for all $t \geqq t_0$. Relation (1.11) implies that the principal matrix solution of $\dot{x}=A x$ is a continuous function of the integrable matrix functions $A$ defined on $[0, t]$ with $|A|=\int_0^t|A(s)| d s$.

When a linear differential equation contains general time varying
coefficients, the remarks in this section essentially comprise the
theory concerning the specific structure of the solutions. For special
equations, much more detailed information is available. For equations
with constant or periodic coefficients, the general structure of the
solutions is known and discussed in Sections 4 and 7.
\end{document}
```

For xelatex you may need to reference the fonts by filename so

```
\setmainfont{texgyretermes-regular.otf}[FakeBold=1]
\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}[FakeBold=1]
```

Comment: Which compiler do you use? I have a hard time reproducing this example. It does not seem to work with pdfLaTex in overleaf and with XeLaTex, the result seem to look differently.

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider  used lualatex but xelatex should be the same but you may need to use filenames, I added a note to the answer